# Linux kernel tags in Emacs

Tags: c, linux, emacs, tags, linux-kernel

So I built the linux kernel tags using the make tags command but for some reason when opening the tags file in emacs (for tag lookups) first it asks if I really want to open the file (which makes sense because the file is a 66mb tag file so that's a lot of definitions) and then after it tries to load it it tells me that it is an invalid tag file. Does the linux kernel tags file just not work in Emacs or is there something that I need to configure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the makefile and see if make tags uses ctags instead of etags. If it does, you may need to do some editing to make it use etags.

To generate a tag file for use within Emacs you have to launch the command `make TAGS` instead of `make tags` as you did. That is, the uppercase «TAGS» option will generate the etags table.

Comment: See  "-e   Output tag file for use with Emacs." for **ctags**

Comment: Yeah after looking into it it was the TAGS directive not tags (case difference) make TAGS creates the correct emacs tag files for the kernel.